# Prove that an $n$-dimensional non-unital algebra over a field $k$ is isomorphic to a subalgebra $\mathfrak{M}_n(k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Assume we have already proved this for unital algebras.

Here's [my book](https://books.google.ro/books?id=Haw6Q4XLsioC&pg=PA206&lpg=PA206&dq=%22A1+is+embedded+in%22+kn%2B1%22&source=bl&ots=E279AW4T--&sig=iXkDVqYfwyLAbvyUMo9cK7FQwtY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=B_aaVZ74H8iqUaPXltAN&ved=0CBMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=true)'s solution:

> Construct the unital algebra $A^1$ [with unit $(1,0)$] as an algebra on the vector space $k\oplus A$ with the multiplication $(\alpha,a)(\beta,b)=(\alpha\beta,\alpha b + \beta a + ab)$. Using Theorem 2.1 [the one we're tying to prove, but in the unital case], $A^1$ is embedded in $k_{n+1}$, hence so is $A$.

What do you think $k_{n+1}$ is? Is it a $n+1$-dimensional field? If so, why have they got this $n+1$ from?

Comment: What book is this? I'm guessing $k_{n+1}$ is the set of $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrices over the field $k$. The $n+1$ is the dimension of $A^1$ which is clearly one more than $A$.

Comment: "Introduction to Ring Theory", Paul Cohn. Ok, so it's another notation for $\mathfrak{M}_{n+1}(k)$. I know I should be finding this really easy, but why does doing the direct sum of $k$ and $A$ increase the dimension of $A$ by 1?

Comment: Sorry, never mind, it's really obvious - ignore that last comment :)

Comment: Isn't it enough to show that $A$ is a subalgebra of $A^1$?

Comment: But $A^1$ is $(n+1)$-dimensional, so it's embedded in $M_{n+1}(k)$. How then conclude that $A$ is embedded in $M_n(k)$?

Comment: I can't, I can just conclude it's embedded in M_{n+1}(k). Is there a way to show that $A$ is embedded in M_n(k), or do you think it's a typo?

Comment: I expect you can make some argument using the fact that $A$ is not unital to strip off a $n \times n$ submatrix which does what you want for $A$. I haven't tried to work it out, but, the existence of the $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ embedding is a nontrivial asset.

Comment: Well, that cost me longer than I had hoped, I bought the book, maybe I'll have more to say once I see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the unital case is given. Then, for $A$ without a multiplicative identity, we construct $A' = k \oplus A$ which consists of pairs $(\alpha,a)$ for $\alpha \in k$ and $a \in A$. As your book suggests, we define:
$$(\alpha,a)(\beta,b)=(\alpha\beta,\alpha b + \beta a + ab)$$
and identify $(1,0)$ serves as the identity for $A'$. Hence $A'$ is unital and of dimension $\text{dim}(A)+1= n+1$. Thus, by Theorem 2.1 of the book, there exists a subalgebra $A'_M \leq \mathfrak{M}(n+1)$. I assume, to say that $A'$ is embedded as a subalgebra of $A'_M \leq \mathfrak{M}(n+1)$ means that there exists an isomorphism of $A'$ and $A'_M$ which takes the abstract product of $A'$ to the product of matrices in $A'_M$. Explicitly, there exists a linear bijection $M: A' \rightarrow A'_M \leq \mathfrak{M}(n+1)$ for which:
$$ M(x'y') = M(x')M(y') $$
for all $x',y' \in A'$. Notice that $0 \oplus A$ is naturally identified with $A$. More to the point,
$$ M((0,x)(0,y)) = M((0,x))M((0,y)) $$
Hence define $\eta(a) = \Psi(0,a)$ and observe $\eta: A \rightarrow \mathfrak{M}(n+1)$ gives an explicit embedding, but, we need to cut it down to size. I found a way to do it just with maps, fortunately I was able to avoid too much calculation in what follows. Mostly we just need a couple natural notations and definitions to go back and forth from the abstract algebra $A' = k\oplus A$ to $k^{n+1}$.

Choose a basis for $A$ and suppose $\vec{a}$ is the coordinate vector of $a \in A$ with respect to the basis. Define $\Psi(\alpha,a) = (\alpha, \vec{a})$. Observe $\Psi: A' \rightarrow k^{n+1}$. Likewise, define $j: k^n \rightarrow k^{n+1}$ by $j(\vec{x}) = (0,\vec{x})$ and $\pi_2:k^{n+1} \rightarrow k^n$ by $\pi_2(x_0,\vec{x}) = \vec{x}$. Given these definitions, 
$$ \Psi^{-1}(j(\vec{x})) = \Psi^{-1}(0,\vec{x}) = (0,x). \ \ \star$$ 
Suppose $a \in A$, we define $L_a: k^n \rightarrow k^n$ as follows: for each $\vec{x} \in k^n$,
$$ L_a(\vec{x}) = \pi_2( \, \Psi( \, M^{-1}[M(0,a)M\left(\Psi^{-1}(j(\vec{x}))\right)] \, ) \, ) $$
notice $L_a: k^n \rightarrow k^n$ is formed by the composition of linear maps and is thus a linear map on $k^n$. It follows $[L_a]$ is an $n \times n$ matrix over $k$ and we will argue that $m(a) = [L_a]$ defines a representation of $A$ in the set of $n \times n$ matrices. Clearly, $m(\lambda a+b) = \lambda m(a)+m(b)$ follows from linearity of the maps and most importantly linearity of the representation map $M$ which gives us $M(0,\lambda a+b)= \lambda M(0, a)+M(0,b)$. Perhaps less trivially, consider how $m$ preserves the multiplication of $A$. Using $\star$ we note:
$$ L_a(\vec{x}) = \pi_2( \, \Psi( \, M^{-1}[M(0,a)M(0,x)] \, ) \, ) $$
But, as $M(0,a)M(0,x) = M(0,ax)$ (this uses the specific construction given by your book if you think about it) we have
$$ L_a(\vec{x}) = \pi_2( \, \Psi( \, M^{-1}[M(0,ax)] \, ) \, )  = \pi_2( \, \Psi(0,ax)) = \pi_2(0,\vec{ax}) = \vec{ax}. \ \ \text{BOB}$$
Well, now BOB has the answer for us, assuming $A$ is **associative**
$$ L_a(L_b(\vec{x}) = L_a(\vec{bx}) = \overrightarrow{abx} = L_{ab}(\vec{x})$$
But, this holds for all $\vec{x} \in k^n$ thus $L_a \circ L_b = L_{ab}$ and thus $[L_a][L_b]=[L_{ab}]$. Therefore, $m(a)m(b)=m(ab)$ for all $a, b \in A$ and we have shown $m: A \rightarrow \mathfrak{M}(k)$ is a representation of $A$.

All of this said, I think direct construction of the **regular representation** on $A$ would be easier. In particular, for each $a \in A$ simply define $R_a(x) = ax$ for each $x \in A$. Then $$ R_a(R_b(x)) = R_a(bx) = a(bx) = (ab)x = R_{ab}(x) $$
Then if we pick a basis for $A$ the matrices of $R_a$ naturally give us a representation of $A$ in the $n \times n$ matrices (assuming again $\text{dim}(A)=n$ and $A$ is associative).

Comment: Unless you find a way to embed $A$ into $M_n(k)$ this answer has no reason to exist.

Comment: @user26857 that is true, it's not a complete answer just yet. I'd like to hear back from the OP before I work on it further, but I'll probably try to hack through it later today.

Comment: @user26857 I use it, so, apparently "never" in incorrect ;) Thanks for looking at it later.

Comment: Reading the answer backwards, let me say that a regular representation on $A$ isn't necessarily an embedding, that is, injective. (For instance, $A$ could be any abelian group with zero multiplication: $a*b=0$ for any $a,b\in A$.)

Comment: @user26857 ok, that explains the problem. We have injectivity because $A'$ has the multiplicative identity.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $A'_M \leq \mathfrak{M}(n+1)$? That $A'_M$ is a subring of the matrix ring of size $n+1$?

Comment: I'm not convinced at all that this answer (very hard to read) really proves that $A$ can be *embedded* into $M_n(k)$.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt I mean in particular $A_M'$ is an $(n+1)$-dimensional  subspace of the $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrices.

Comment: @user26857 perhaps you can improve by adding your own answer? I do grant that my current write-up has not explicitly addressed the issue of injectivity and it would be interesting to see how this all fleshes out in your Abelian group with the trivial multiplication.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I've never claimed that a non-unital $n$-dimensional $k$-algebra can be embedded into $M_n(k)$ although this is the logical analogue of Theorem 2.1 from Cohen, and I'm also not sure if Cohen asked us to prove this in exercise 6 on page 58. Instead you aimed to prove this and in my opinion failed.

Comment: @user26857 wait a minute, the whole reason I tried to embedd $A$ into $n \times n$ matrices was your comment yesterday, "Unless you find a way to embed A into Mn(k) this answer has no reason to exist." which now that I read the original question again, I probably should have ignored. If I read the original problem correctly, we just needed to embedd $A$ in the $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrices. So, the difficult second half of my answer is not needed.

Comment: @user26857 ok now I see what you are saying... I just wanted the question to be more interesting than the notational question... I asked an expert on this stuff and he tends to doubt the validity of my proof as well just on the principle of the thing. But, he hasn't looked at it yet.

Comment: For instance, if $A=k$ with zero-multiplication, then I don't think there is an embedding $A\to k$. (I don't know what's going on for $\dim_kA>1$, but I guess the conclusion is similar: there is no embedding $A\to M_n(k)$ that works for every $A$.)

Comment: @user26857 However, for an associative algebra of dimension $n$ over $k$ we can embedd it in $M_{n+1}(k)$. I believe that is the analog which Cohn intended with the exercise ( I got the book yesterday and I think this is a fair reading). Somehow, my "$m$" must fail to be injective by your one-dimensional comment. The reason is hidden in my formula somewhere, I will ponder it.